# Google compute instance available informations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is there a gcloud, or python API, equivalence to the information Google supplies in the OS patch management GUI.  The GUI lists compute instances with package updates available.
I can use *gcloud compute os-config vulnerability-reports describe* to view CVE reports, but not if a patch is available.
Any suggestions on how to obtain this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method [*projects.locations.instances.inventories.list*](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1/projects.locations.instances.inventories/list) will provide you with all the required information

As explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1/projects.locations.instances.inventories/list), this method will list inventory data for all VM instances in the specified zone. After specifying the [*parent*](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1/projects.locations.instances.inventories/list#path-parameters) parameter the output was the following one:

```
{

  "inventories": [

    {
      "osInfo": {
        "longName": "Deb*** ******** ** (*****)",
        "shortName": "*******",
        "version": "***",
        "architecture": "*******",
        "kernelVersion": "* *** ***** *.**.***-* (****-**-**)",
        "kernelRelease": "*.**.*-**-*****-****",
        "osconfigAgentVersion": "**********",
        "hostname": "***************"
      },

      "name": "***/****8**8***/l********s/*s-**as***-*/i******/2*******98**4/*****",
      "updateTime": "****-**-*****:**:**.******"
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "************=="
}
```

As explained in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1/projects.locations.instances.inventories/list#query-parameters), the `view` parameter value should be set to [FULL](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1/InventoryView), otherwise its default value will be *BASIC*. If *FULL* value is not used, the method won’t provide you with the available packages and the already installed ones.

As seen in this example:

```
{
      "osInfo": {
        "longName": "Deb*** ******** ** (*****)",
        "shortName": "*********",
        "version": "****",
        "architecture": "*********",
        "kernelVersion": "#********* (*********)",
        "kernelRelease": "*********",
        "osconfigAgentVersion": "*********",
        "hostname": "*********"
      },

      "items": {
        "availablePackage-google-clo*****************-********* ********": {
          "id": "****availablePackage-goo************************************",
          "originType": "*********",
          "type": "*********",
          "availablePackage": {
            "aptPackage": {
              "architecture": "*********",
              "version": "*********",
              "packageName": "***************************"
       …

       …
```